# How to send notification to the device through gcm

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Hi i am getting this message when i try to test gcm with php and MySQL,i don't,know how to integrate gcm with PHP and MySQL

```
 {"multicast_id":7670730794440128024,
"success":0,"failure":1,
"canonical_ids":0,
"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Comment: Please post the code that is producing this error.

Answer (score -1):

Check your API Key is correct or not in Google’s API console.